# Can I solve a diffusion equation in a bounded geometry by the Laplace transform method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, heat-equation

I would like to solve the diffusion (or heat) equation
$$ f_t(x,t) = D f_{xx}(x,t)$$
with the boundary conditions
$$f(0,t)=f(H,t)=0$$
and
$$ f(x,0)=\delta(x-x_0)$$
That is, the initial distribution starts somewhere in the interval $0 < x_0 < H$, and the heat is absorbed at the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=H$.

**Standard Approach:**

The usual approach is to construct an Eigenfunction expansion. One sets $f(x,t) \propto e^{-\lambda t} g(x)$ and finds $g_\lambda''(x) + (\lambda/D)g_\lambda'(x)=0$, finding ultimately that
$$ f(x,t) = \sum_\lambda A_\lambda g_\lambda(x),$$
where the eigenmodes and coefficients are selected to meet the boundary and initial conditions.

**Desired Approach:**
In my case, I would like the solve this problem by Laplace transforms. I believe this should be possible despite the bounded domain of $x$ due to the successful application of this technique to a similar (but much more difficult) problem by [Masoliver and Porra (1996)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.189).

According to these authors, we can simply take the Laplace transform over space $\mathcal{L}\{f(x,t)\}(g) = \int_0^\infty dx e^{-g x} f(x,t) $,despite the upper boundary. This obtains the differential equation
$$\tilde{P}_t(g,t) = - g^2 \tilde{P}, $$
giving solution in Laplace space
$$\tilde{P}(g,t) = A(t) e^{-g^2 t}.$$
The initial condition $\tilde{P}(g,0)=1$ gives $A(0)=1$, but the transform over $g$ does not invert to a known solution, so I am not sure how to proceed. Any thoughts are appreciated on how to solve the diffusion equation with Laplace transforms.